# ModuleNotFoundError in a Python project using packages

Tags: python, package, importerror

I have a Python project (python 3.6) with a rather simple package structure. My goal is to have a package containing modules which are reused across other packages. Here is the structure:

```
    my_project                   
    ├── /docs           
    ├── /src
    │   ├── __init__.py                
    │   ├── /common
    │   |    |── __init__.py      
    │   |    |── common_module.py
    │   ├── /packageA
    │   |    |── __init__.py      
    │   |    |── modA.py
```

The problem is that when I do the following inside `modA.py`:

```
    from src.common import common_module as cm
```

I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named src.common`

What I have tried so far is

- making sure I have a correct package structure as in `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html`
- extending the PYTHONPATH in the virtual environment I am using by `export PYTHONPATH=<path_to_project>/src`
- placing an `__init__.py` inside `/my_project` as well
- read other question on StackOverflow but none of them provided a solution. Some of them were doing hacky stuff with `sys.path` that was said to not a good solution even if it would work.

None of these worked and I have been struggling with this problem for a while now so any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this import to work, PYTHONPATH would need to be `.../my_project`, not `.../my_project/src`.

Comment: That solved it - thank you for the quick answer! I just have a follow up regarding importing modules from the same package. If in `/common` we have another module called `helper.py` I now cannot import `helper` into `common_module` using a simple `import helper` but need to give a full path as `from src.common import helper`. Why is that and why could I import simply before?

Comment: When you import a module, the first name in the import must be a direct child of a directory in your PYTHONPATH.  For example, if your PYTHONPATH is `/home/petar/modules`, and you want to import the `/home/petar/modules/car/engine.py` module, you would say `import car.engine`.  In your question, you changed your PYTHONPATH to be one directory higher, so you had to change your import to also start one directory higher.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation - it really helps to get a better feel for python paths.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should put `__init__.py` in `project`,
then `export PYTHONPATH = <LOCAL_PATH_TO_...>/project`